# Python appending list, nothings added

Tags: python, python-3.x

as I was practicing some of python question, there was something that I didn't understand
Below is my code

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    answer = []
    participant.sort()
    completion.sort()
    for i in range(len(completion)):
                   if participant[i]!=completion[i]:
                       answer.append(participant.pop(i))
                       return answer
    return answer


solution(["leo", "kiki", "eden"],["eden", "kiki"])
solution(["marina", "josipa", "nikola", "vinko", "filipa"], ["josipa", "filipa", "marina", "nikola"])
```

I have to find the names from the first list that are not in the second list.
Obviously I have to get "leo" for the first one and "vinko" for the second one.

However whenever I tried to append the element from participant, it added nothing
Why does that happen and how do you fix it??

Comment: Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Because you only iterate `completion` which is a shorter list than `participant`, therefore you never see `leo` or `vinko`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you do not need to use any kind of sort, unless of course you want the results in order.

Secondly there is a great way to check if an element is not in a list using 'not in'

Hope this helps :)

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    answer = []
    for p in participant:
        if(p not in completion):
            answer.append(p)

    print(answer)    
    return(answer)
```

The solution for including when there is duplicate names. as requested in the comments below:

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    answer = []
    for p in participant:
        if(p not in completion or participant.count(p) > completion.count(p)):
            if(p not in answer):
                answer.append(p)

    print(answer)    
    return(answer)
```

So above I am checking for the differences in count between the number of occurences of the element in each list, if the first list is greater than the second, therefore their must be more of that element in the first. Also I am making sure not to add duplicates to the resulting list(not sure if this was required)

Comment: Why loop through indices when you can loop through the actual list?

Comment: I was trying to use some of the existing logic from question, but yes that is a far better way

Comment: what if you also want to get another person with the same name?
Like if the participant list is["mislav", "stanko", "mislav", "ana"], and the completion ["stanko", "ana", "mislav"]

In this case I want to get the second "mislav"

Comment: So if there is two of one name in one and one of one name in the other, then the resulting output should include the name?

Comment: mmm ok well that changes the scope. I will add the other solution above

Comment: Using set intersections is a nicer way and probably a quicker way of finding items in both lists - sssuming you don’t care about repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting output because you are iterating loop only 2 times, as length of completion list is 2 only, And as you are sorting both partition and completion list so your first two elements will be same. Hence it will not execute code inside your if block.
Same thing for the second call, it will iterate loop only 4 times.

You can achieve your expected result with minimal code using set. Refer solution provided by Tomothy32

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try doing something simpler using a hashed set in python.

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    answer = []
    completion_set = set(completion)

    for p in participant:
        if p not in completion_set:
            answer.append(p)
    return answer


print(solution(["leo", "kiki", "eden"],["eden", "kiki"]))
```

Can also be achieved with a normal list.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is likely flawed - looping through indices while removing items is a recipe for disaster.

Luckily, your problem can easily be solved through set logic:

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    return list(set(participant) - set(completion))
```

Examples:

```
solution(["leo", "kiki", "eden"],["eden", "kiki"])
# ['leo']
solution(["marina", "josipa", "nikola", "vinko", "filipa"], ["josipa", "filipa", "marina", "nikola"])
# ['vinko']
```

Answer (score 0):

A more optimized and suitable selection of the collection for this would be "set". See how the lines of code is reduced!!

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    answer=set(participant).symmetric_difference(set(completion))
    #symmetric difference will do (AUB)-(AnB), which is what you need
    return list(answer)


solution(["leo", "kiki", "eden"],["eden", "kiki"])
solution(["marina", "josipa", "nikola", "vinko", "filipa"], ["josipa", "filipa", "marina", "nikola"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using len(completion) in the for loop range which is less than the length of the participant.thats why nothing is appending

Answer (score 0):

The problem is while you are sorting `leo` and `vinko` goes at the last index of `participant`. and you are looping till `completion` size. so `leo` and `vinko` never gets to checked.
You can try this:

```
def solution(participant, completion):
    answer = []
    participant.sort()
    completion.sort()
    for i in range(len(participant)):
        # if participant[i] != completion[i]:
        if participant[i] not in completion:
            answer.append(participant[i])
            return answer
    return answer


print(solution(["leo", "kiki", "eden"], ["eden", "kiki"]))
print(solution(["marina", "josipa", "nikola", "vinko", "filipa"], ["josipa", "filipa", "marina", "nikola"]))
```